# sort a STL container based on a getter member function, with no extra code written

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Let's consider the following code sample:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class A
{
public:
    A( const std::string& name ) : name( name ) {}

    inline const std::string& getName() const { return name; }

private:
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.push_back( A("b") );
    v.push_back( A("a") );

    // want to sort the container, based on it's name!
}
```

I know how to do this (either define an internal or external `operator<`, or declare a functor struct/class providing a `operator()` and pass it to the `std::sort` fonction), for instance:

```
bool operator<( const A& a ) const
{
    return getName() < a.getName();
}
```

However, I'm lazy having to do this every time I want to sort a container based on a contained class attribute, specially when the class provides a getter function for it.

Is it possible to request the sort to be done based on the class member function result value (if this one has a comparator available, obviously)?

Something like:

```
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), &(A::getName) );
```

Without having to declare a new operator or functor?

Optional question: What if vector contains pointers (`std::vector<A*> v`)...can a one-line statement sort it based on `A::getName` result?

Comment: Range TS should allow `std::sort(v, &A::getName);`.

Comment: It would be great....but it reports `invalid use of non-static member function 'const string& A::getName() const'` (see http://cpp.sh/7eqf)

Comment: If you use C++11 or greater, you can use lambda : `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const A& a, const A&b) { return a.getName() < b.getName(); });` : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d083786114cfb4e8

Comment: By TS, I mean it is not yet in standard :-(

Comment: @Jarod42: Ok, did not know that....so the question is not that stupid then ;-)

Comment: You may look at some library as [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) which adds [Projection](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html#algorithms-should-take-invokable-projections).

Comment: Note that the ranges TS always needs to take a comparator when you feed it a projection, so the call would actually be `std::sort(v, std::less<>{}, &A::getName);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can a use a lambda function to sort your vector:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [] (A const& a, A const& b) {
        return a.getName() < b.getName();
    });
```

It is longer than your version but you don't need to write anything prior to a call of `sort`.

If you need to do that kind of stuff often, you could put everything in a small functor (and allow it to work for both `A`, `A*` and smart pointers), it uses [`mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) (thanks to @T.C.):

```
template <typename T, typename R>
struct cmp_attr {

    using fun_t = R (T::*) () const;

    cmp_attr (fun_t g) : _g(g) { }

    template <typename U>
    bool operator() (U const& a, U const& b) const {
        auto fn = std::mem_fn(_g);
        return fn(a) < fn(b);
    }

private:
    fun_t _g;
};

// Utility function to have template parameters deduced, a like std::make_pair
template<typename T, typename R>
auto make_cmp_attr (R (T::*g) () const) {
    return cmp_attr<T, R>(g);
}
```

Then:

```
struct A { const std::string& getName(); }
struct B: public A { }

std::vector<A> v1; // vector of A
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), make_cmp_attr(&A::getName));
std::vector<A*> v2; // vector of A*
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), make_cmp_attr(&A::getName));
std::vector<B> v3; // vector of child class
std::sort(v3.begin(), v3.end(), make_cmp_attr(&A::getName));
std::vector<B*> v4; // vector of pointer of child class
std::sort(v4.begin(), v4.end(), make_cmp_attr(&A::getName));
```

Comment: You may write a functor to allow both `a.*cmp` or `a->*cmp`.

Comment: It would be a little more complicated to be really generic (handle any smart pointer)s and would require SFINAE I think. but should be enough for OP.

Comment: @Jarod42 I've updated the answer with (what I think is) an acceptable solution to handle most of the cases.

Comment: Just `mem_fn`-wrap the thing and let `INVOKE` do the rest. (In C++17 you can use `std::invoke` directly.)

Comment: @T.C. Wow, this shorten the code so much... Thanks! I just have to find if I can store `mem_fn` in `_g` directly.

Comment: @Holt It's a very trivial wrapper, so there isn't much point.

Comment: @Holt: Thank you. Very complete answer. And lambda solution is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not overloading `operator<` just because you have one particular use case in mind. Keep the sorting logic local to where you need it; it's not part of the type.

If you want to sort by projections regularly, it may be worth writing a little helper:

```
template <typename C, typename R>
struct SortByPred
{
    using P = R (C::*)() const;

    P const p_;
    SortByPred(P p) : p_(p) {}

    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(T const & lhs, T const & rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.*p_)() < (rhs.*p_)();
    }
};

template <typename C, typename R>
SortByPred<C, R> SortBy(R (C::*p)() const)
{
    return SortByPred<C, R>(p);
}
```

Usage:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), SortBy(&A::getName));
```

Comment: You may even write operator to allow both `a.*p_` or `a->*p_`.

Comment: @KerrekSB _"... it's not part of the type"_ - it can be though. At the other _far end_ of the spectrum there are the builtin types, like `int`, which are inherently sortable by `<`. Somewhere in the middle are types like `std::string` that by default sort using "string sort", but as well (depending on semantics) _could_ sort by length or even (archaic, I know, but still...) capacity. As you move through the spectrum to the other end, separating the type from it's sorting behavior becomes more important, I think.

Comment: @JohannGerell: If the comparison is part of the type and also provides the order by which the OP wants to sort the container, then the question is moot. So I'm assuming that that isn't the case. The OP said that he's specifically overloading the operator in order to achieve the particular sorting order.